# Real Newbie Question

Tags: data-request, metadata

My interest is in visualizations from the standpoint of a software developer, not a scientist. It seems that getting open data from two different sites take a lot of work as some expose an API and some just let you download JSON and do what you like. My question is...Is there a central repository of metadata for open data that is easily accessed? Has anyone thought of doing this legwork?

Answer (score 3):

There's [Data.gov](http://www.data.gov) for U.S. federal government open data, and [Datahub](http://datahub.io/) for international open data, as a start.

Comment: I dont see where to access the raw data and metadata on opendata.gov(I am assuming the metadata is embedded int the raw json file. Ive gotten data from Marylands opendata site and the data is easy to get at.

Comment: On Data.gov, if you click the name of a dataset, it shows all the raw metadata. It is also accessible via the site-wide API. The documentation is at: https://www.data.gov/developers/apis